# Output sorted text file from Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a `PCollection<String>` in Google Cloud DataFlow and I'm outputting it to text files via `TextIO.Write.to`:

```
PCollection<String> lines = ...;
lines.apply(TextIO.Write.to("gs://bucket/output.txt"));
```

Currently the lines of each shard of output are in random order.

Is it possible to get Dataflow to output the lines in sorted order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not directly supported by Dataflow.

For a bounded `PCollection`, if you shard your input finely enough, then you can write sorted files with a [`Sink`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/Sink) implementation that sorts each shard. You may want to refer to the [`TextSink`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextSink.java) implementation for a basic outline.