# Output data appears in a random order when uploaded to google cloud storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I've been using the google-dataflow-sdk to upload CSV files to google cloud storage.
When I upload the file to a google cloud project, my data appears in a file in a random order on the cloud. Each line on the csv is correct, but the rows are all over the place.

The header of the csv )i.e. attribute, attribute, attribute) are on another line all the time and never at the top where is should be. I stress again, the data in each column is fine, it is just the rows that are randomly positioned.

here is the code which reads the data initially:

```java
PCollection<String> csvData = pipeline.apply(TextIO.Read.named("ReadItems")
                                             .from(filename));
```

and this is the code that writes to the google cloud project:

```java
csvData.apply(TextIO.Write.named("WriteToCloud")
                          .to("gs://dbm-poc/"+partnerId+"/"+dateOfReport+modifiedFileName)
                          .withSuffix(".csv"));
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst i agree the answer provided by Graham Polley is correct, I managed to find a much simpler way to get the data to write in an ordered way.

I instead used the google cloud storage library to store the files I would need onto the cloud, like so:

```java
public static String writeFile(byte[] content, String filename, String partnerId, String dateOfReport) {
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.defaultInstance().service();
    BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("dbm-poc", partnerId + "/" + dateOfReport + "-" + filename + ".csv");
    BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.builder(blobId).contentType("binary/octet-stream").build();
    storage.create(blobInfo, content);

    return filename;
}

public static byte[] readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));
}
```

Using these two methods in conjunction with each other, I was not only able to upload the files to the bucket i wanted without losing any of the contents ordering, but i was also able to change the format of the uploaded files from text to a binary/octet-stream file which means it can be access and downloaded.

This method also seems to remove the need to have a pipeline to upload data.

Comment: Yes i decided against it. I was unsure that there was an easier alternative

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to fix your header use:

```
public static TextIO.Write.Bound<String> withHeader(@Nullable String header)
```

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Write#withHeader-java.lang.String-

For example:

```
...
TextIO.Write.withHeader("<header>").apply(..)
...
```

Secondly, Dataflow does not currently support ordered/sorted writing to `Sinks`. This is mostly likely due to its distributed/paralell architecture. You could write your own custom `Sink` if you really wanted to. See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110258/output-sorted-text-file-from-google-cloud-dataflow) for more details.